# How to export from Emacs org-mode to both LaTex and OpenOffice with biblatex citations

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I write my social science research papers in Emacs org-mode. I would like to export these either to LaTeX or OpenOffice (to save in MS Word format) and have it look presentable either way, with similar formatting including footnotes, citations and bibliography entries.

Hitting `C-c C-e` in an org-more file will load the export screen, which does include LaTex exports and they work pretty well. This screen used to also include OpenOffice exports by default in earlier versions of Org, and they can still be enabled (in version 8.1 at least) by running `org-export-odt-convert`. But these exports do not work well at all. LaTeX tags are unsurpisingly included verbatim rather then processed. This means the bibliography is mising entirely from the OpenOffice file, and the citations and formatting are all wrong.

Is their a solution?

Comment: I installed latex2rtf which may turn out to be an acceptable solution,  if I can only figure out how to get it to work...

Comment: You are using an old version of orgmode. Please get version 8.x, because it comes with a completely new exporter.

Comment: I'm now on Org 8.1, will update question / answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, which depend on whether you're using Emacs' built-in package installation functionality (M-x package-install) or either use-package.el or straight.el. If you haven't done so yet, I encourage you to switch to [straight.el](https://systemcrafters.net/advanced-package-management/using-straight-el/) as most of the Emacs community seems to use it as of today (and gives snippets according to its own syntax).

[According to Kristoffer Balintona](https://kristofferbalintona.me/posts/202206141852/), you can't export to ODT with biblatex. You can only use biblatex (or natbib, which the author doesn't recommend) with LaTeX, as the Org manual says already:

> In contrast, two other processors target LaTeX and LaTeX-derived formats exclusively:

(Which is followed by descriptions of natbib and biblatex.)

If you want to export your references to ODT, you need to setup either the basic or the CSL citation export processor. Kristoffer recommends the CSL so let's go with that.

First go to [citationstyles.org](https://citationstyles.org/), the official CSL website. It links to [the Zotero repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) which contains a variety of citation styles. Download the ones that fit to your discipline conventions and language.

If you aren't an English monolingual then you're going to have to internationalize your CSL export processor with [this repository](https://github.com/citation-style-language/locales). You may just clone it with e.g. `git clone https://github.com/citation-style-language/locales ~/Documents/csl-locales`.

Then you're either going to insert the following snippet in your configuration file (which may be either `init.el` or loaded by it with e.g. `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/org-cite.el")`:

```
(require 'org)
(require 'oc-csl)
(require 'oc-biblatex)

(setq org-cite-global-bibliography '("~/Documents/zotero_bibliography.bib"))

(setq org-cite-csl-styles-dir "~/Documents/styles-csl") ; which is the path to the directory where your CSL styles are stored
(setq org-cite-csl-locales-dir "~/Documents/csl-locales")

(setq org-cite-export-processors
  '((latex biblatex authoryear) ; author-year citation style example for latex
; (latex biblatex) this snippet works too for the default citation style
  (t csl "revue-francaise-de-sociologie.csl") ; for any other export processor, fallback to CSL
  ))
```

If you're feeling uncomfortable with the syntax of a given variable, you should be able to safely customize it with `M-x customize-variable`.

If you wish to setup CSL and BibLaTeX with the straight.el packages manager, you should read Kristoffer's blog post and especially [the configuration subsection](https://kristofferbalintona.me/posts/202206141852/#configuration).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found so far was to install the package `tex4ht`. This allows me to run the shell command `mk4ht oolatex [filename].tex` on the LaTeX file once I export it from org-mode, and this produces an ODT files which looks pretty good in LibreOffice. Apparently this mk4ht command is not compatible with `biblatex`, but if I use the BiBTeX package `natbib` instead, it works fine.

Unfortunately, when I save it in MS-Word format, whether DOC or DOCX, the bibliography disappears. But hopefully I can find a further solution to that.